# problem in setonClickListener in ListView on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

in a list view i set a image view , 3 image buttons and two text views. i have to set `setoncliklistener` for each image button. i did in the following way but i get `NullPointerException`. in my xml i give `android:onClick="OnClick"` for each image button. this is my code: please help me. i post code,xml,logcat.

```
    public class AndroidList extends ListActivity{
ImageButton ib1,ib2,ib3;
 public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener{

public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,String[] objects) {
 super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  //  View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  View row = convertView;  

  if(row==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
   row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
  }

  ib1=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);  // line no 53 ..   NullPointerException
  ib2=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
  ib3=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
  ib1.setOnClickListener(this);
  ib2.setOnClickListener(this);
  ib3.setOnClickListener(this);
  row.setTag(position);
   TextView textfilePath = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
   textfilePath.setText(_videosId[position]);
   ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

    Bitmap bmThumbnail;
    int ids;
    ids=Integer.parseInt(_videosId[position]);
    bmThumbnail= MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null); 
    // bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(_videosId[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
    return row;
}

@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag(); // here i get position 
  switch(v.getId()){
  case R.id.imageButton1:  
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"play  "+position,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   // position print as null
  break;
      case R.id.ImageButton2:
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"play2  "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // position print as null
      break;
      case R.id.ImageButton3:
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"play3  "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // position print as null
      break;
}

}

}

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    initVideosId();
    setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(AndroidList.this, R.layout.row, _videosId));
  }

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.e("video", "called");
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  
    private void initVideosId() {
        ........... 
    }

  }
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <image view>....</image view>
     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1 ... ></ImageButton>
      <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton2 ... ></ImageButton>
     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton3 ... ></ImageButton>
  </LinearLayout> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Log cat:

```
06-10 11:43:37.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2504): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 11:43:37.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at      com.exercise.AndroidList.AndroidList$MyThumbnaildapter.getView(AndroidList.java:53)
 06-10 11:43:37.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
  06-10 11:43:37.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
 06-10 11:43:37.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
 06-10 11:43:37.563: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2504):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
```

............... 
please help me.

Comment: I suggest you do some more debugging. Perhaps break up the line. So grab `Integer buttonId = R.id.imageButton1;` before hand, and log it's value. Then fetch the view `View buttonView = findViewById(buttonId);` and log its class. Then cast it to an ImageButton `ImageButton button = (ImageButton) buttonView;`. Then assign it to the variable `ib1 = button;`. Hopefully somewhere you'll find the problem

Comment: this code makes me cry ... really, this code looks like you copy someone's else code from random sources and paste it to one file :) ... ImageButton ib1,ib2,ib3; in top class ?? they should be local vars in getView ... or better look at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html ... by calling findViewById(R.id.imageButton1) in getView you call findViewById from activity **not from list item**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order.

```
View row = convertView;  
  if(row == null){
   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
  }

  ib1=(ImageButton)ROW.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);  // line no 53 .. NullPointerException
  ib2=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
  ib3=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
  ib1.setOnClickListener(this);
  ib2.setOnClickListener(this);
  ib3.setOnClickListener(this);
  row.setTag(position);
```

First you get the row. After that you are trying to inflate something from nowhere. what if row is null in the first step?

P.S. Do not forget **ROW**.findViewById(..

Comment: i change my code as you given in answer i get same error at the same position. please help me.

Comment: you didn't change you code ... ib1=(ImageButton) **row** .findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

Comment: @Pepi i'm sure he didn't change the code ... error is here `ib1.setOnClickListener(this)` coz ib1 is null and your answer is good(he is calling findViewById for activity not for a listitem)

Comment: Pleasee...read carefully...as i said:

ib1=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
  ib2=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
  ib3=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

you forget ROW.findviewById

Look at my example again..

Comment: its works thanks, i made change as you told. but i print position it gives null to me. please help me. thanks

Comment: please check  "public void onclick(view v){...} "in my code. if print position value in toast. it display null. pls....

Comment: It is normal...The view that you set the position is ROW..this is the entire ListItem. The parameter of OnClick(View v) is the button view, which view do not hold position. Set tag to this view. You can not cast View to Integer..

Comment: i set as row.settag(position) in public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ... }. sorry if i am wrong. please help me.

Comment: just set the tag to the button. ib1.setTag(...). What do you want to do at all? I think there is something wrong in your idea.

Comment: my need is , i have a list view in that 3 image buttons. if i touch play image button of last row of list view that corresponding video to be played.

Comment: You don't have to pass the position parameter.Just use it..

final int currPosition = position;
View row = convertView;  

  if(row==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

then use this in OnClick(View v) {... if(currPosition==..) }

Comment: i have a new problem with switching into next activity. i get  android your content must have a listview whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.list'. please help me.

Comment: i give extends ListActivity in next activity. i remove that it work. thanks and sorry for delay.

Comment: please see my question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393997/null-pointer-exception-on-set-on-click-listener-in-list-view-on-android/6394075#6394075" regards list view

Answer (score 0):

I think its getting null because layout is not set yet...

```
if(row == null)
{....}
```

move this section to just below of:

```
View row = convertView;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have "if(row==null) below of view row = convertView"  in my code;

Comment: it runs but please check "public void onclick(view v){...} "in my code. if print position value in toast. it display as  null. pls....